# Unable to install requests in VS Code for working with Python

Tags: windows-10, python, sudo, visual-studio-code

I am unable to install the requests using sudo command in my VS Code terminal.

```
sudo pip3 install requests

sudo : The term 'sudo' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path 
was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ sudo pip3 install requests
+ ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (sudo:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: You have this tagged as Windows 10, which according to VS Code docs (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal) would mean that the default shell would be PowerShell, which wouldn't recognize sudo. Did you change the shell?

Comment: Yeah right. It is unable to recognize sudo. @KevinRockwell